# What is suitable way to create a blog

Tags: php

I'm going to create a my own blog using php. I want to clarify whether it is good idea to do it with php? Or else any idea about php with wordpress?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - We're not here for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is fine but that's one of the most used platform. Because of this, that make Wordpress a target of choice for hackers.

You WILL be "scanned" everyday, so you have to maintain security at the highest and expect a hack if you don't.

You can use a solution where you can contribute locally and then push static files on a remote server. With such a solution, your blog will have a very small attack surface and won't be targeted by mass scanners.

This one is a good one : https://blog.getpelican.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are not surposed to ask that kind of questions here but I suggest you checkout https://laravel.com

You can find a step-by-step guide on building a forum here:

https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel

I bet you can figure out how to build a blog out of that information.